# adding sequential number to existing data specific to an ID MySQL

Tags: mysql

New to the forum.I wonder if somebody out there might be able to help with an issue I am having?

I need to add an addition column in a query to show a sequential number 1,2,3...ect but to have it be specific to an existing ID - The `s_id` based on the order of the `s_id`. Below show an example of the data I am working with.

```
'p_id' 's_id'

'327'  '569'

'330'  '569'

'1205' '569'

'350'  '1000'
```

I am aiming to get it to look like this.

```
'Seq_no'   'p_id'  's_id'

'1'         '327'  '569'

'2'         '330'  '569'

'3'         '1205' '569'

'1'         '350'  '1000'
```

I have looked at adding an auto increment bur cannot manage to tie it back to the back specifically to the `s_id`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Best Regards
DSW

Comment: Where is the connection between the `Seq_no` and the rest of the table? I don't get it. And do you want to add this column only in output or permanent in the structure of the table?

Comment: All, Apologies for the delay. Thanks very much for the answers. I went with the self join in the end. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a self join :

```
SELECT count(s.sid) as seq_no,t.p_id,t.s_id
FROM YourTable t
JOIN YourTable s 
 ON(t.s_id = s.s_id AND t.p_id >= s.p_id)
GROUP BY t.p_id,t.s_id
```

Comment: ...If we make certain (reasonable) assumptions about the data

Comment: Yes of course. This answer is by the assumption that the logic he presented in the data sample is the logic of the table.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is using `MySQL user defined variables`.

In your case you need two of them.

```
SELECT 
 @rn := IF(@sameSid = s_id, @rn := @rn + 1 , 
        IF(@sameSid := s_id, 1, 1)
 ) AS Seq_no,
 p_id,
 s_id
FROM your_table 
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT @sameSid := 0, @rn := 1
) AS var 
ORDER BY s_id , p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're sorting the dataset by (s_id,p_id) then here's one way (untested):

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev = x.s_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i 
     , @prev := s_id prev
  FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
 ORDER
    BY s_id,p_id;
```